# How to add background color in React native svg charts?

Tags: react-native, react-native-svg-charts

I am using [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-svg-charts) package to create a custom multiple `LineChart`.

The only problem I'm facing is that I need to add a background color between each 2 y values (I know for sure that there will be only values from 0 to 4). So i have to add a color between "0-1" , "1-2" and "2-3".

Here is the current result

[image]

and this is what I need to achieve

[image]

Here is my code

```
<YAxis
   data={dataAxeY}
   style={{ marginBottom: xAxisHeight }}
   contentInset={verticalContentInset}
   svg={{ fill: "rgba(134, 65, 244, 0.5)", fontSize: 16 }}
   numberOfTicks={4}
 />
<View style={{ flex: 1, marginLeft: 10, borderWidth: 2 }}>
          <LineChart
            yAccessor={({ item }) => item.value}
            xAccessor={({ item }) => item.date}
            style={{ flex: 1 }}
            data={data}
            contentInset={verticalContentInset}
            svg={{
              strokeWidth: 3,
              stroke: "url(#gradient)",
            }}
            svg={{ stroke: "rgb(134, 65, 244)" }}
            curve={shape.curveNatural}
          >

          </LineChart>

          <XAxis
            data={dataAxeX}
            formatLabel={(_, index) => dataAxeX[index].dateName}
            contentInset={{ left: 10, right: 10 }}
            svg={{ fill: "rgba(134, 65, 244, 0.5)" }}
          />
        </View>
      </View>
```

I tried to add a `Rect` which I specified the fill color like this

```
const ColoredRect = (({ y }) => (
  <Rect
     x="0"
     y="0"
     width="100%"
     height="33%"
     fill="rgb(0,0,255)"
  />
))
```

It was added but I want a more generic solution.

I hope you can help me solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

[Starting from the version 5.0](https://github.com/JesperLekland/react-native-svg-charts#children), you can now create children SVG to the chart and place it below using `belowChart= {true}`.

So for example you can do something like this:

```
<View style={{flex: 1}}>
  <LineChart
    style={{flex: 1}}
    data={yAxisValues}
    yMin={-10}
    yMax={10}
    contentInset={verticalContentInset}
    svg={{
      stroke: strokeColorLeft,
      strokeWidth: '2',
    }}>
    <Svg belowChart={true}>
      <Rect
        x="0"
        y="40%"
        width="100%"
        height="20%"
        fill="rgb(144,238,144,0.3)"
      />
      <Rect
        x="0"
        y="0"
        width="100%"
        height="20%"
        fill="rgb(173,216,230,0.3)"
      />
    </Svg>
    <Grid />
  </LineChart>
  <XAxis
    data={xAxisValues}
    formatLabel={(value, index) => index}
    contentInset={verticalContentInset}
    svg={axesSvg}
  />
</View>
```

That gives you this result :

[image]